# Improve performance on write-only table?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, netty

I am using MySQL 5.5 with innoDB. The basis of my server is Netty, JDBC and BoneCP.

I have a log table that contains user inputs(HTTP header, request body etc). This table will only be read very rarely for reasons like security and data recovery. Therefore the read performance is not something we care about.

There are five columns in this table.

```
Name       | Type
--------------------------------------------------
logID      | big Integer(auto-increment)(primary key)
userNumber | medium integer
logTime    | timestamp
header     | varchar(100)
body       | varchar(200)
```

What are some tips that will improve the insert performance?
Also, is the logID neccessary for this case?

Comment: Avoid indexes besides the one on the auto-increment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the table is never referenced, why do you use any key at all in there? It's not like it's necessary. It only adds to the insert time, and serves no purpose.

My suggestion would be to drop the logID and not create any indexes on the table at all.

Another optimization would be to change the table type to myISAM. When you only insert and have no constraints on the table, InnoDB will cost you time for the option of ACID compliance, while myISAM doesn't care about that.

Comment: I agree about the ACID compliance. However(correct me if I'm wrong), MyISAM does not support row level locking. Concurrency is important to be because blocking I/O is a bad practice when using Netty(which I use).

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not familiar with Netty. I can only tell you that in my experience you can do several dozen inserts per second into such a table I described with no locking problems whatsoever, as there is no locking occuring.